# Laravel foreach not working

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I did everything like I did before but for some reason it's not working. This is my code in blade

```
<select name="partner_id" id="partner_id" class="form-control">
                    @foreach($partners as $partner) 
                        <option value="{{ $partner->id }}">{{ $partner->name }}</option> 
                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

and this is code in my controller

```
public function create()
    {
        $partners = Partner::all()->get();
        return view('createcompany', compact('partners'));
    }
```

and this is my route

```
Route::get('/create-company', function () {
    return view('createcompany');
})->middleware('auth','admin');
```

and I get this error

```
Undefined variable: partners (View: .../resources/views/createcompany.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Although this answer would answer OP's second bug, this answer does not answer the question. It was a bad route that returned a view without variables.

Change

```
public function create()
{
    $partners = Partner::all()->get();
    return view('createcompany', compact('partners'));
}
```

To

```
public function create()
{
    $partners = Partner::all();
    return view('createcompany', compact('partners'));
}
```

As the `all()` method already implicates a `get()`.

Comment: It's still same.

Comment: After i removed that and changed route, it's working, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed route to 
`Route::get('/create-company', 'CompanyController@create');`
and removed ->get()

```
$partners = Partner->all();
```

Now it's working, thanks.

Comment: Just about to comment that haha